# Reduce the background simultaneously as site reduction - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a site and my goal is to make it responsive by reducing the background associated by when the site is reduced.

[image: Site]

I want the grey area to reduce simultaneously when the site is reduced horizontally.
How can I achieve this?

Here is my code so far. I'm using bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="@CurrentPage.siteDescription">

    <title>@CurrentPage.pageTitle|Gymnasiestudera</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700,300,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fanoe.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <header>
            <div class="row col-md-12">
                <nav class="entry-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="~/" title="För elever">För elever</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/for-skolpersonal/" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/ungdom-och-elevdatabas/" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <a href="@home.Url">
                        <div class="brand" style="background-image:url('@(home.SiteLogo)?height=100&width=700&')"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 main-nav">
                    <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="meny cbp-hrmenu col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        @{ Html.RenderPartial("MainNavigation"); }
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="toggle" class="toggle">
                <a href="#" class="cross"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        @RenderBody()
        <div class="foot-line-background">
            <div class="foot"></div>
        </div>
        <footer class="field dark">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <br />
                        @home.sidfotKolumn1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <br />
                        @home.sidfotKolumn2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <br />
                        @home.sidfotKolumn1
                    </div>


                </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- Javascripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/fanoe.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/Custom.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like its time for you to check the @media rules in css

Comment: @Adarsh @ media is not the solution to my problem becuase  @ media only changes the design on a condition. What I want to do is to change it simultaneously  as the site reduces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you really just need to have a max-width on your "content container" to do the job. As the window width decreases, the gray area will also decrease until the container takes up the full window.

```
.my-container {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/6s4u14yd/1/

Comment: But 'm using bootstrap `<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">` to make the position right. Can I somehow set it as max with?

Comment: You should be able to use all those bootstrap grid classes for the children of your main container. `<div class='my-container'><!-- inside, lots of children nested inside .my-container with grid classes --></div>`